# UIScrollView constraints unexpected behaviour

Tags: swift, uikit, constraints

I have a simple log in view implemented as follows :

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    private var safeArea : UILayoutGuide!
    
    private let scrollView : UIScrollView = {
        let view = UIScrollView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
        return view
    }()
    
    private let containerView : UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    private let logoView : UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        view.image = UIImage(named: "logo")!
        return view
    }()
    
    private let emailOrPhoneTextFieldView : UITextField = {
        let view = UITextField()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        view.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        view.placeholder = "Email or phone"
        view.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)
        view.textColor = .black
        view.autocapitalizationType = .none
        view.tintColor = UIColor(named: "myColor")
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGray
        
        return view
    }()
    
    private let passwordTextFieldView : UITextField = {
        let view = UITextField()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        view.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        view.placeholder = "Password"
        view.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)
        view.textColor = .black
        view.autocapitalizationType = .none
        view.tintColor = UIColor(named: "myColor")
        view.isSecureTextEntry = true
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGray

        return view
    }()
    
    private let logInButtonView : UIButton = {
        let view = UIButton()
        view.setTitle("Log in", for: .normal)
        view.setTitleColor(.white, for : .normal)
        view.setBackgroundImage( UIImage(named: "blue_pixel")!, for: .normal)
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addTarget(self, action: #selector(logInButtonClickedHandler), for: .touchUpInside)
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        safeArea = view.layoutMarginsGuide

        setupViews()
    }

    
    private func setupViews()
    {
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        containerView.addSubview(logoView)
        containerView.addSubview(emailOrPhoneTextFieldView)
        containerView.addSubview(passwordTextFieldView)
        containerView.addSubview(logInButtonView)

        scrollView.addSubview(containerView)

        let constraints = [
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.bottomAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor),

            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),

            logoView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 120),
            logoView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            logoView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            logoView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor),
            
            emailOrPhoneTextFieldView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            
            emailOrPhoneTextFieldView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            
            emailOrPhoneTextFieldView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: logoView.bottomAnchor, constant: 120),
            emailOrPhoneTextFieldView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            
            passwordTextFieldView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailOrPhoneTextFieldView.bottomAnchor),
            passwordTextFieldView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailOrPhoneTextFieldView.leadingAnchor),
            passwordTextFieldView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            passwordTextFieldView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailOrPhoneTextFieldView.trailingAnchor),
            
            logInButtonView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: passwordTextFieldView.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            logInButtonView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: passwordTextFieldView.leadingAnchor),
            logInButtonView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: passwordTextFieldView.trailingAnchor),
            logInButtonView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            logInButtonView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor)
            
            
        ]
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }
 
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)),
                                               name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
                                               object: nil)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)),
                                               name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
                                               object: nil)
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }

    @objc private func logInButtonClickedHandler() {
        print("button pressed")
    }

}

//MARK: Keyboard Notifications
private extension LoginViewController {
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

            scrollView.contentInset.bottom = keyboardSize.height
            scrollView.verticalScrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
        }
    }
    
    
    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        scrollView.contentInset.bottom = .zero
        scrollView.verticalScrollIndicatorInsets = .zero
    }
}
```

Everything is fine with the implementation but 2 things looks very strange for me and I guess I misunderstood smth

1. If I comment out

   containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),

I see that my container view does not fit the whole screen width (actually it's about 50% of it)

Why? I set trailing and leading constraints to scrollview, which is 100% of view width.

2. If I comment out

   logInButtonView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor)

I don't get button click events and I'm not able to input anything inside textfields. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

1. From the Apple Docs:

> Constraints between the edges or margins of the scroll view and its
> content attach to the scroll view’s content area.
>
> Constraints between the height, width, or centers attach to the scroll
> view’s frame.

Hence you need the width constraint in order to make the contentView the full width of the ScrollView's frame.

2. As above, without that constraint the contentView only has constraints to the top/bottom edge of the scrollView this doesn't define its height and so you need to add full top-to-bottom constraints on the subviews of the contentView in order to define its height.

If you use the `View Hierarchy Debugger` you'll see the contentView has 0 height without that constraint (it just isn't clipping the content), hence why you can't tap on any controls.

It's worth giving the ['Working with Scroll Views'](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html) section of Apple Auto-Layout docs a read.